# Linq to populate a Treeview Control : Live filtering

Tags: c#, linq

I'd like to update a Treeview when a user click on a tickbox.
I have a single Datatable with artists / albums / songs / and some other criteria.
The treeview contains 2 levels : the Artist and the albums (1 or many per artist)

So i have an original linq query which is the following :

```
var query = (from i in Globals.ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable() 
            select new { art = i.Field<string>("artiste"), alb = i.Field<string>("album"), dis = i.Field<string>("disque") })
            .Distinct()
            .GroupBy(g=> g.art)
            .OrderBy(g => g.Key);
```

The "disque" is an additional information to filter the Treeview depending on the type of album (LP or 12" or both)
I then have 2 foreach loops that populate the treeview nicely (the query doesnt show the songs which is great to have the count of albums per artiste)

I'd like to update the query "live" when the user click on the boxes (LP, 12" or both)
so i have the following (i have the same linq for the 12"):

```
  if (!LP.Checked)
        {
            query = query.Where(p => (string)p.dis != "LP") ;
        }
```

But the "p.dis" is not available, i only have the "p.key" which is the artiste.

How can i use the .where at that step ?
Thanks

Comment: it's so simple if you use ``Dictionary<,>`` instead ``IEnumerable<IGrouping<,>>``

Comment: can you please elaborate on that (i'm not familiar with Dictionary tbh) ? Thanks

Comment: i will elaborate it like an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Without using `Dicionary`**:

If you need to filter all `artist` that not have any `disque` calling `LP`, change little your code:

1 - change `orderBy` and `GroupBy` order to return `IEnumerable<IGrouping<>>` instead`IOrderedEnumerable<IGrouping<>>`

```
var query = (from i in Globals.ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable() 
    select new { art = i.Field<string>("artiste"), alb = i.Field<string>("album"), dis = i.Field<string>("disque") })
    .Distinct()
    .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
    .GroupBy(g=> g.art);
```

2 - in the second query, use `where` function:

```
if (!LP.Checked)
{
    query = query.Where(x => !x.Any(p => p.dis == "LP"));
}
```

**Using `Dicionary`**:

If you want to filter inside grouped values, then
you can use `Dictionary<>` instead of `IEnumerable<IGrouping>` returned by `GroupBy` function,like the follwing Code:

1 - in the first query, use `ToDictionary` to convert `IEnumerable<IGrouping>` to `Dictionary<>`

```
var query = (from i in Globals.ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable() 
    select new { art = i.Field<string>("artiste"), alb = i.Field<string>("album"), dis = i.Field<string>("disque") })
    .Distinct()
    .GroupBy(g=> g.art)
    .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());
```

2 - use a simple `Where` inside `ToDictionary` to filter values for each `artist` group, like the following code :

```
if (!LP.Checked)
{
    query = query.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Value.Where(p => p.dis != "LP").ToList());
}
```

The second query, will filter inside values.

Documentation:

[dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8)

[todictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=netframework-4.8)

I hope this will help.

Comment: @Sebastien Chemouny, can you check the answer and tell me if you don't understand any part of code.

Comment: it's great Sajid, it works like a charm :) just great. That's the flexibility i was looking for !

Answer (score 1):

Try and look at this simple demo. Perhaps it can guide you how to achieve what you want to:

```
void Main()
{
    var data = new List<Data>
    {
        new Data { Art = "Art1", Alb = "Alb1", Dis = "LP"},
        new Data { Art = "Art1", Alb = "Alb2", Dis = "12"},
        new Data { Art = "Art2", Alb = "Alb1", Dis = "LP"},
        new Data { Art = "Art3", Alb = "Alb1", Dis = "LP"}
    }; 

    var query = 
        (from i in data
        select new Data { Art = i.Art, Alb = i.Alb, Dis = i.Dis })
        .Where(WhereFunc())
        .Distinct()
        .GroupBy(g => g.Art)
        .OrderBy(g => g.Key);
}

static Func<Data, bool> WhereFunc() => (p) =>
{                
    if (!LP.Checked)
    {
        return (string)p.Dis != "LP";
    }
    else
    {
        return (string)p.Dis == "LP";
    }
};

public class Data
{
    public string Art {get; set;}
    public string Alb {get; set;}
    public string Dis {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, spent the last 30 mn on it. While i understand the approach, i'm struggling on the Func WhereFunc. specially the <Data, bool> part : Data would mean the "p.Dis" and the bool the "==LP" ? I have one main issue with the query (regardless of the where function) is that it returns all the songs in the query and not only the artiste and albums (my original query was doing that) which makes it impossible to populate the treeview (or not straightforward). do you know why ?

Comment: Right. `Func<Data, bool>` is a delegate or any function that accepts an object of type `Data` (`p` in this case - it can be any letter) and return `bool`. Regards to your second issue, I can't say anything as I don't see you select songs in your query.

Comment: ok, this delegate is neat, thanks ! the second issue, i think the .distinct() is doing the trick as each artist have 1 to many album and each album have 1 to many songs. i dont want to get the songs in the result as they are not part of the Treeview. Here, if an album has 9 songs, i have 9 times the same artist and 9 times the same album which i want to avoid :)